# Use UWP in WPF Application Throws Error "generating manifest"

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, uwp

I want to use the OCR component of UWP in an WPF C# app.This is done by using a C# class library in other projects. On build I get the following error shown below. How can I get this to compile?

> Error 1 Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly
>   '{MyAppPath}\Windows.winmd' or one of its dependencies. Attempt to
>   load a program with an incorrect format.

The picture shows the references:

[image]

The files are:

System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll

Windows: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd

The Code I want to use (not in a finsished state, I just want it to compile)

```
using System;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.Media.Ocr;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace tegBase
{
    public class Scan
    {

        public static async void OcrAusfuehren()
        {

            var fileName = @"C:\a.jpg";
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileName);

            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

            var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

            SoftwareBitmap b;
            b = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

            OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromUserProfileLanguages();
            var s = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(b);
            Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrResult c = s;
            Console.WriteLine(c.Text);

        }
    }
}
```

Update:

I tried to reproduce the error on another PC, there however, the UnionMetadata folder is empty. So I took the winmd from 10.0.16299.0, but it lead to the same result.

[image]

I also tried changing the target framework from .net 4.5.1 to 4.6.1, which also did not solve the problem. On a sidenote: changing it to 4.7.1 was not possible, as VS said it was not installed. Installing 4.7.1 was also not possible, with the installer message beeing: Higher Version already installed.

Comment: Net 4.5 is 64 bit while you have X86 checked which is 16 bit.  I would create a class library project for all the win32 methods and then build you main project as 64 bit and use the win32 as a reference project.

Comment: @jdweng What are you talking about? .net can target 32 or 64 bit Windows, x86 and x64 respectively, but not 16 bit Windows

Comment: I tried to create a new WPF app and a c# class library which include your above and the UWP dll file, but it could work well in my side. Could you have a try to create a new WPF app to test it again? Or provide a project to help me see the issue.

Comment: I just created a blank app and class library, which also worked fine. I will try to built it up a little more, until the error occurs.

Comment: @Mister832 Can you change your startup project to UWP App instead of WPF and try to see if that works?

Comment: Do you mean an empty UWP app without any references? Yes, this works.

Comment: @Mister832 Could you provide a project to help me see the issue? and what is your device OS version and OS build?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the UWP software development kit (SDK) and migrate the package to package references. This must be done in order to use all the UWP libraries within a WPF/WinForms/Console application. Please visit this website for a step-by-step tutorial: https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/26/calling-windows-10-apis-from-your-wpf-application/